# iOS Present an Ad Modal VC over main VC

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an ad that presents as a modal over my main VC. The ad is timed - show once per app launch after the user has been using the app for 5 seconds. The following is in the main VC which has modal VC's being pushed.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"firstLaunch"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"paidIAP"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]] ) {

        [self performSelector:@selector(showAdUnit) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0f];
    }

}

}


-(void)showAdUnit{
    NSLog(@"got to show ad unit");


    [ADNetwork showAd:ADNetworkShowStyleInterstitial rootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];

}
```

However, if the user goes to another section of the app prior to 5 seconds, the ad will not launch because of this warning

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Basically, the ad will never show. How can I make the ad show exactly once per launch over the main screen even if the user clicks to push other screens? If this is not possible, how can I push the ad over any screen they happen to be on?

Answer (score 0):

You should present it over your main window `rootViewController` like this :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:adViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This one will always have its view in the view hierarchy and you are guaranteed that your ad view controller will be presented above everything else.

Comment: So just present from the `rootViewController`. What if I get a reference to `rootViewController` in `viewDidLoad` of the main screen and then user goes to another screen? It would change and same problem.

Comment: Dont pre-get the reference to `rootViewController` ! Just get it when you need to present like i did.

Comment: Make the call in `AppDelegate`?

Comment: No. Can you add the code for your `showAdUnit` method so I can show you how ?

Comment: By the way, do you know you can use `@(1)` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` ? This will look much better :)